# How to authenticate nextjs API requests?

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js

I want to make sure that request to my API are 'authentic' and/or coming from reasonable user.

```
export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { method } = req;
  const userId = req.query.id;
  const userCookieId = req.cookies?.uid || req.cookies?.guestId;
  const authUser = userId === userCookieId;
}
```

I've tried something like this, but `userCookieId` is undefined on first load? Only works when a user refreshes the page. I set the cookie before I make a request to the API, but I'm assuming the cookie is still slower than when needed when I start `authUser`.